# Java JTable vector with objects filling

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I've been trying to fill a JTable for about three days. All I need to do is fill a vector of vectors with "Artikel" objects, fill a header vector and bind these two vectors to a JTable.

I could manage this with using a custom AbstractTableModel but I couldn't create a addColumn() method. So, I gave up this way. Now I just use standard DefaultTableModel but now I can't get my JTable right filled. I get all my objects in the first column instead of separated to the all columns:
[fault screenshot](http://www.okyanus.be/vraag.jpg)

[image: GUI]

My Artikel class:

```
public class Artikel {

private String EnitiativeRef;
private String Brand;
private String pnb;
.
.
.
public Artikel(){        
}

public String getEnitiativeRef() {
    return EnitiativeRef;
}

public void setEnitiativeRef(String EnitiativeRef) {
    this.EnitiativeRef = EnitiativeRef;
}
.
.
.
}
```

My button code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    ICsvBeanReader inFile = null;
    String[] header = {};
    Vector<Vector<Artikel>> data = null;

    try {
        inFile = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader("C:\\609661920071022111.csv"), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        header = inFile.getHeader(true);

        data = new Vector<Vector<Artikel>>();

        Artikel artikel;
        while ((artikel = inFile.read(Artikel.class, header, cellProcessor)) != null) {
            Vector<Artikel> tmpVector = new Vector<Artikel>();
            tmpVector.addElement(artikel);
            data.addElement(tmpVector);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("FOUT: " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            inFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    tblAll.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, new Vector(Arrays.asList(header))));
    tblAll.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
}
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong or guide me to the right way of doing this? I will really appreciate your grateful help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Hard-code values for the CSV data.

Comment: Note: potentially long running tasks (file I/O, DB access..) should **not** be done on the EDT.  GUI updates should **only** be done on the EDT.  That code seems to be mixing the two.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: `bs.Artikel@67780b07` is the form usually used for printing arrays or collections.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm not sure I agree with your last comment. It's a sign of no adequate `toString()` override, but not of arrays.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  You are probably correct. :P

Comment: Looks to me that you are not filling the DefaultTableModel correctly. You are adding Artikels while you should add each value of each column independently. Anyway, it would be a lot easier if you extend `AbstractTableModel` and rely on you `Vector<Artikel>`

Comment: See also this [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274644/how-i-can-use-arraylist-to-store-my-data-in-predefined-default-table-model-for-j/13275274#13275274)

Comment: If you're interested in hiding/showing columns, you might like to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492217/how-to-make-a-columns-in-jtable-invisible-for-swing-java) and [this](http://www.stephenkelvin.de/XTableColumnModel/). I personal prefer the second approach, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: your suggestion about 'Concurrency in Swing' was something I thought but never knew what/how it is, thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in the vector of vectors represents a row and each element of the those element vectors represent a column.

You are adding one-element vectors to the main vector, and the element is an object of the class for which you haven't implemented the `toString` method.

You are probably going the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses guys! Now I begin to see what I'm doing wrong.I've just implemented the toString method in the 'Artikel'      class as follows:   `@Override public String toString(){return EnitiativeRef + " " + Brand + " " + pnb;}`   The result still appears in the first column but this time each object's values appended toegether as one row:[screenshot](http://www.okyanus.be/vraag2.jpg). I know this behaviour is quite normal because of my toString implemantation. Can you give me an example with adding each value of each column independently using DefaultTableModel?

Comment: The problem is solved by using objects inside vector instead of vectors in vector. So, changed the `Vector<Vector<Artikel>> data` to `Vector<Artikel> data` .
I can also do now anything I want with a standard custom AbstractTableModel. The trick is updating vector and then model if you want to make a change in the JTabel(update record,add column..).
Thank you all for your responses and made me think the right way of updating JTable.