# Unable to populate SummaryTable with results

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablemodel

```
    private void myProfileTabStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                          
    if (myProfileTab.getSelectedComponent() == EditProfile) {
        editProfile();
    } else if (SearchAcademic == myProfileTab.getSelectedComponent()) {
        AcademicDAO aDao = new AcademicDAO();
        try {
            List<AcademicDTO> listAll = aDao.listAll(AcademicDTO.class);
            searchTable.setData(listAll);
        } catch (DBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}  





public class ListDataUI<T extends BaseDTO> extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public ListDataUI() {
        this.summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames = Collections.emptyMap();
        this.dtoSummaryFields = Collections.emptyList();
        this.summaryTableModel = new SummaryTableModel();
        initComponents();
        this.summaryTable.setModel(summaryTableModel);
        initListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form ListDataUI
     */
    public ListDataUI(LinkedHashMap<String, String> summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames) {
        this.summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames = summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames;
        this.dtoSummaryFields = new ArrayList<String>(summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames.keySet());
        this.summaryTableModel = new SummaryTableModel();
        initComponents();
        this.summaryTable.setModel(summaryTableModel);
        initListeners();
    }

    public ListDataUI(List<String> dtoSummaryFields) {
        this.summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames = Collections.emptyMap();
        this.dtoSummaryFields = new ArrayList<String>(dtoSummaryFields);
        this.summaryTableModel = new SummaryTableModel();
        initComponents();
        this.summaryTable.setModel(summaryTableModel);
        initListeners();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tableSp = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        summaryTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        summaryTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        tableSp.setViewportView(summaryTable);

        add(tableSp, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTable summaryTable;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane tableSp;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private List<T> data;
    private Map<String, String> summaryColumnsAndTheirViewNames;
    private List<String> dtoSummaryFields;
    private SummaryTableModel summaryTableModel;

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void removeSelectedDataRow() {
        final int selectedRow = summaryTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (selectedRow != -1) {
            final int modelIndex = summaryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
            data.remove(modelIndex);
            summaryTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(modelIndex, modelIndex);
        }
    }

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
        summaryTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        if (data.size() > 0) {
            summaryTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to show the row data from database in the table `searchTable` , to which I invoke the `setData()` method. I set a breakpoint at the line `searchTable.setData(listAll);', listAll has all the data from database, but doesnt showup on searchTable.

Comment: Source for SummaryTableModel would be nice. I think you simply forget to set the data to the model.

Comment: At which line are you populating `summaryTable` with data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at not moment is the model of your JTable connected to your data. So your JTable and its TableModel have absolutely no knowledge of that `List<T> data`.

So basically you need to have a `TableModel` that receives your list and then fires an appropriate `TableModelEvent`. The `TableModel` should implement very few basic methods that indicate how to access the data and which data to display.

Find below a very basic example of such implementation (here it is based on a `List` of  `Person` to display first name and last name). It should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to your case:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestListTableModel {

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Person> baseModel;

        public MyTableModel() {
            baseModel = new ArrayList<TestListTableModel.Person>();
        }

        public MyTableModel(List<Person> baseModel) {
            super();
            this.baseModel = new ArrayList<Person>(baseModel);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return baseModel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "First Name";
            case 1:
                return "Last Name";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return getPersonAtIndex(rowIndex).getFirstName();
            case 1:
                return getPersonAtIndex(rowIndex).getLastName();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Person getPersonAtIndex(int rowIndex) {
            return baseModel.get(rowIndex);
        }

        public int getIndexOfPerson(Person person) {
            return baseModel.indexOf(person);
        }

        public void addPerson(Person person) {
            baseModel.add(person);
            fireTableRowsInserted(baseModel.size() - 1, baseModel.size() - 1);
        }

        public void removePerson(Person person) {
            int removed = baseModel.indexOf(person);
            if (removed > -1) {
                baseModel.remove(removed);
                fireTableRowsDeleted(removed, removed);
            }
        }

        public void setBaseModel(List<Person> baseModel) {
            this.baseModel = baseModel;
            fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this));
        }

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        List<Person> personModel = new ArrayList<TestListTableModel.Person>();
        personModel.add(new Person("John", "Smith"));
        personModel.add(new Person("Peter", "Donoghan"));
        personModel.add(new Person("Amy", "Peterson"));
        personModel.add(new Person("David", "Anderson"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestListTableModel.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        tableModel.setBaseModel(personModel);
    }

    public class Person {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestListTableModel().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create a [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) to your `JTable`. Any update on the data should be done on the table model.

Set the data to the `TableModel`. If each row is an `Object` then add objects to the TableModel list.

Then set the model to your table using `setModel` method. Ex: `table.setModel(customModel);`

**P.S:** Prefer [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) where all the required methods have been implemented, than going for [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).

Comment: I kind of disagree with your last statement. AbstractTableModel implements all methods except 3  of them: `getRowCount`, `getColumnCount` and `getValueAt` which are, to my opinion, very essential and using the DefaultTableModel will work as well but without any benefit if you are working with a List (You will be wasting your time converting the List to Vector's).

Comment: Totally agreed conversion takes time. But my point is `AbstractTableModel` needs to call `fireXXMethod` explicitly rt? So I thought why to even do that if there is an `api` there which has implemented it correctly.